# Unity3d webplayer failed to download data file

Tags: unity

When testing my game web builds on localhost, I get the error "Failed to download data file". The game data file is correctly placed, and the page loads fine, it just wont download the plugin, or prompt me to do so.

I tried the following things:
Add MIME Types to IIS 7.5:

1. Open IIS Manager
2. Double click "MIME Types" in the IIS section.
3. Click Add on the right side "Actions" menu.
4. File name extension: = .unity3d
5. MIME type: application/unity3d
6. click ok
7. Restart the server (right side "Actions" menu)

That didn't work for me specifically because it turned out I was using IIS Express, so I did the following:

If Windows 7, browse to 'C:\Users\\Documents\IISExpress\config\' and open the file: ApplicationHost.config.

Search for 'staticContent' and add the following before the closing tag:

However, again, it didn't work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution in my situation was to add a web.config file and place it in the same directory as the WebPlayer.html and 'gamename'.unity3d files.

The content of the web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
           <mimeMap fileExtension=".unity3d" mimeType="application/vnd.unity" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```